# Transform text to double between -1.0 and 1.0 for use as a seed [postgresql]

Tags: sql, postgresql, random

I need to generate a random value using `random()` based on a seed which comes from an existing table. The seed is a text but `setseed()` requires a double between `-1.0` and `1.0`. The reason is that I need the random number to be the same given an existing value in my database.

I want to define a function that takes the seed and returns a random number based on that seed:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION random_with_seed(seed text) RETURNS double precision AS
    $$
        DECLARE casted double precision;
        BEGIN
            -- cast seed to a double between -1.0 and 1.0
            casted = ???

            setseed(casted);

            RETURN random();
        END
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```

What would be the best way to transform the text into a valid argument for `setseed()`?

Comment: `setseed(salt::float)`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It has to be a value between `-1.0` and `1.0` as far as I understood. Simply casting it might yield a value outside of that range, doesn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT cos(hashtext('some text'));
         cos         
---------------------
 -0.9092973651315766
(1 row)
```

Comment: Hell yeah, I should revisit some math classes. Thanks alot.